# Python Telebot Photosize

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I am creating a telegram Bot for python, the idea is to receive an image and then process it.
I can already get the picture but I have trouble saving.

I have not found a way to save it.

e.g. telebot.download_file (file, path)

I have not had results

```
# Handles all sent documents and audio files
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def photo(*mensaje):
    for m in mensaje:
        chat_id = m.chat.id     
        user = m.chat.username
        nombreChat = m.chat.first_name
        print "ID CHAT",chat_id
        print "*************************"
        print "*************************"
        print "Nombre de usuario", user
        print "*************************"
        print "*************************"
        print "Nombre Chat",nombreChat
        print "*************************"
        print "*************************"
        print m.photo[0]
        print "*************************"
        print "*************************"
        print m.photo[1]
        print "*************************"
        print "*************************"
        print m.photo[2]
        print "*************************"
        print "*************************"`


[result][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

From Telegram Bot Api [documentation page](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getfile):

[image]